# How can i improve this MySQL query speed with a large IN list, large LIMIT offset and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

```
SELECT 
mp_library.`lid` AS itemId, 
mp_library.`cid` AS itemCategory, 
mp_library.`photo` AS itemPhoto, 
mpl_names.`name` AS itemName, 
mp_users.`uid` AS userId 
FROM mvc_public_library AS mp_library 
INNER JOIN mvc_public_library_names AS mpl_names ON mpl_names.lid = mp_library.lid 
LEFT JOIN mvc_public_wishlist AS mp_wishlist ON mp_wishlist.lid = mp_library.lid AND 
          mp_wishlist.uid = 31 AND mp_wishlist.status = "1" 
LEFT JOIN mvc_public_users AS mp_users ON mp_users.uid = mp_wishlist.uid AND 
          mp_users. STATUS = "2" 
WHERE 
      mp_library.status = "1" AND 
      mpl_names.language = "en" AND 
      mp_library.cid IN (3, 9967, 4, 20, 5, 9950, 6, 9971, 7, 9979, 12, 271, 272, 13, 2502, 2503, 15, 9925, 630, 778, ... , 3184 ) 
ORDER BY mp_library.lid DESC 
LIMIT 268320, 48
```

The query above has between 1000 and 3000 IDs inside the IN (...) section.

The EXPLAIN statement outputs:[image]

In all the joined tables i have set indexes.
The duration of the query is about 8 seconds, which is a very long time.
If i eliminate the JOINS and run only `SELECT * FROM mvc_public_library WHERE cid IN (...)` the query takes 3 seconds, again, a very long time.

Do you have any suggestions what might i do to decrease the query time? I've noticed in other posts that the large IN lists are a problem, the large LIMIT offset is a problem, the ORDER BY is a problem, here i have all 3 :)

**@LATER EDIT**

I managed to reduce the query to this (without the list):

```
SELECT mp_library.`lid` AS itemId,mp_library.`cid` AS itemCategory,mp_library.`photo` AS itemPhoto,mpl_names.`name` AS itemName,mp_users.`uid` AS userId 
FROM mvc_public_library AS mp_library 
INNER JOIN mvc_public_library_names AS mpl_names ON mpl_names.lid = mp_library.lid 
LEFT JOIN mvc_public_wishlist AS mp_wishlist ON mp_wishlist.lid = mp_library.lid AND 
          mp_wishlist.uid = 31 AND 
          mp_wishlist.status = "1" 
LEFT JOIN mvc_public_users AS mp_users ON mp_users.uid = mp_wishlist.uid AND 
          mp_users.status = "2" 
WHERE 1 AND mp_library.status = "1" AND 
            mpl_names.language = "ro" 
ORDER BY mp_library.lid DESC 
LIMIT 268320,48
```

Also i've added the indeces @DRapp suggested and got an improvement from 8 seconds to 5 seconds. I was wondering if it can be further improved. Here is the explain statement of the new query:[image]

Comment: How long does the query take if you remove the `order by`?  Same `limit`, same everything else.  Can you list the indexes on the tables (in the question)?

Comment: almost the same as if it were there, only 0.5/1 second improvement

Comment: For me it's odd that the chosen key is `status` which usually is not restrictive at all.

Comment: The ORDER BY is fairly simple to address with an index.  Using `IN` with a large literal list is going to be particularly slow - can you join the subquery that would generate those id's instead?

Comment: In some cases like this, you could actually see performance increase by using a subselect for the IN portion and joining to the subelect results as an aliased table.  This can help limit the result set off the bat. This is a little counter-intuitive to the typical approach of trying to avoid subselects, but in these sort of scenarios, it is worth testing to see if you get better results.

Comment: I agree with Mike Brant. With such a large number of records, avoid the extraneous JOINs as well as the large number of comparisons against the IN list and do the subselect first.

Comment: the problem is that if i remove the large IN list completely from the query, the query still runs for 6.5-7 seconds, so the bulk of the slowness is not from that list, as far as i can tell

Comment: How many rows is this query returning? What's the schema? Is photo a blob?

Comment: the photo is the EXPLAIN statement of the query, the query returns 48 rows, but from the EXPLAIN statement i see that it matches 147505 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the key to the problem is that you need an index on `mp_library(status, cid)`.  In fact, the following index would cover the query:

```
create index on mp_library(status, cid, lid, photo)
```

Comment: the index you suggested, improves the speed by 1 second

Comment: MySQL is not likely to use the index on 'cid' for lookups. It's likely scanning all rows where 'status' = 1 and comparing each row against the list of values in the IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would have covering indexes on all the tables such as

```
table                     index
mvc_public_library        ( status, cid, lid, photo )
mvc_public_library_names  ( lid, language, `name` )
mvc_public_wishlist       ( lid, uid, status )
mvc_public_users          ( udi, status )
```

Also, I've slightly rewritten and if the 1 second improvement is not better, I would add the keyword

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... rest of your query.
```

Comment: with your suggestions, the speed went from 8 seconds to 5 seconds. although an improvement i was wondering if it can be lower like 2-3 seconds or something like that. (the STRAIGHT_JOIN didn't do any improvement to the 5 seconds)

Comment: @Bogdan, with 1000 - 3000 IN list, the only thing I can think of is preparing that list in numerical order so the engine doesn't have to.  If it is forcing to go back and forth?  I don't know.

Comment: i have removed the list from the query, i have updated my first post to reflect the changes.